# Line item should change the price

Tags: ajax, commerce

I have this problem in Drupal Commerce: a line item should change the price of my product, that is based on customizing the users (ex. product base $10 with customization $12, customization is line items).

This is possible working on Rules, but you only see final price after you add the product on cart, I should instead see the price change in ajax so the users see final process before add to cart.

I've not found solutions online. The basic scenario is like this:

- You buy a shirt based  =$10
- The user customizes the shirt with your name and = $12
- The user customizes name and logo = $14

I am working with Kickstart 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you're looking for doesn't exist at the moment. I'd describe it as wanting line item field value changes to trigger a refresh of the Add to Cart form and the injected product fields. You can follow this feature request, though I'm not sure it's likely to be addressed soon:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1541886

Answer (score 0):

So you have fixed prices and a set of fields per kind of price? Ha! You could setup a line item type per product:

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/malberts/1947762

And then create three products:

1. Shirt, Price $10
2. Shirt + Name, Price $12, custom line item type: Name
3. Shirt + Name + Logo, Price $14, custom line item type: Name + Logo

Then create one Product Display node and attach those three products to the display node.

In theory, that should work. Let me know how the "in practice" goes.

EDIT: Here's how to do it, step by step in a video:

http://youtu.be/eaF_FjnQ8NM

Josh

Comment: Hi Josh, I often follow your tutorials and articles. :) 

I tried to follow the directions in the link you've written but I can not get it to work. There are some changes to the source code to adapt the module? But this solution seems just what I need. I would like to make it work. Do you have an example link?

Comment: I'll take this idea for a spin on Monday.

Comment: Hi Josh, ty for your time. This video is really a good solution for me. I followed all step u say but in kickstart 2 but there is a problem on "Use custom line item type" check box, i check this but drupal not save this check.

Comment: Yeah, it's important to build on Kickstart 1. Kickstart 2 is more like a demo/proof-of-concept. If you are adding fields to line items, it's likely Kickstart 2 is too opinionated to be flexible enough for your use case.

Comment: Oh, ok, really Kickstart 2 is only like a demo? I have done latest 2 e-commerce with K2 and it work well. I can't now switch to K1 coz is too late :(